# How to convert text field with formatted currency to numeric field type in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql-11

I have a table that has a text field which has formatted strings that represent money.
For example, it will have values like this, but also have "bad" invalid data as well

```
$5.55
$100050.44
over 10,000
$550
my money
570.00
```

I want to convert this to a numeric field but maintain the actual numbers that can be retained, and for any that can't , convert to null.

I was using this function originally which did convert clean numbers (numbers that didn't have any formatting). The issue was that it would not convert $5.55 as an example and set this to null.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cast_text_to_numeric(
    v_input text)
    RETURNS numeric
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
declare v_output numeric default null;
begin
    begin
        v_output := v_input::numeric;
        exception when others then return null;
    end;
return v_output;
end;
$BODY$;
```

I then created a simple update statement which removes the all non digit characters, but keeps the period.

```
update public.numbertesting set field_1=regexp_replace(field_1,'[^\w.]','','g')
```

and if I run this statement, it correctly converts the text data to numeric and maintains the number:

```
alter table public.numbertesting
alter column field_1 type numeric
using field_1::numeric
```

But I need to use the function in order to properly discard any bad data and set those values to null.

Even after I run the clean up to set the text value to say 5.55
my "cast_text_to_numeric" function STILL sets this to null ? I don't understand why this sets it to null, but the above statement correctly converts it to a proper number.

How can I fix my cast_text_to_numeric function to properly convert values such as 5.55 , etc?

I'm ok with disgarding (setting to NULL) any values that don't end up with numbers and a period. The regular expression will strip out all other characters... and if there happens to be two numbers in the text field, with the script, they would be combined into one (spaces are removed) and I'm good with that.

In the example of data above, after conversion, the end result in numeric field would be:

```
5.55
100050.44
null
550
null
570.00
```

FYI, I am on Postgres 11 right now

Comment: End up with a period? So `$550` should become NULL? you should be more precise. [edit] the question, don't add comments.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  and 9.5 will be EOL in 8 days - you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the ticket to show what I wanted for desired outcome of the conversion. FYI, I am on postgres 11, but didn't see the group when choosing to post.